# Is there a way to extract a TXT file and convert it into a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have this code:

```
 @echo off 
 (for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do echo %%L) >list.bat 
:::@echo off
:::echo hello
:::pause
```

and it takes the simple "hello" script and turns it into a batch file called **list.bat**. The problem is that I need to put that code there every time. However, I want to extract a file with that code inside of it, *for example*, I have **list.txt** and I want to extract the code from it. The way I have tried is below I do not know what is going on. It says

> The system cannot find the drive specified

for every line of code inside of **list.txt**

When I put `echo` before **%%s** it shows all lines of my code inside **list.txt**.

What am I missing?

```
@echo off 
(for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%l in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do echo %%l) >list.bat 
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (list.txt) do (
   %%s
)
pause
```

List.txt looks like this:

```
:::@echo off
:::echo hello
:::pause
```

The file that is going to be created (list.bat) looks like this:

```
@echo off
echo hello
pause
```

Comment: It doesn't help, your question is still unclear. What do you mean by `load it`, open it in a text editor? or run it? Also `set /p code=<list.txt` or more correctly `set /p "code=" 0< "list.txt"` is defining a variable `%code%` with the content of the first line of `list.txt`, it isn't placing the entire content of your file as a variable, you can run as a batch file.

Comment: What's wrong with using `@Set "code=@Echo Hello.&Pause"`, then using `%code%`, whenever you need to display the pointless message bloat `Hello.` and wait for a keypress?

Comment: use `.cmd` instead of `.bat` as it is really old and used seldom. but I believe this is what you want? `@(for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%L in ('type list.txt ^|findstr /b ":::"') do @echo %%L)>list.cmd`

Comment: Don't use `delims=:` to get rid of the leading colons, use [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.clm/nt/syntax-replace.html) instead; don't forget about [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for that…

Comment: I have added `(for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%l in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do echo %%l) >list.bat` and when i do `%%s` on its own it says `The system cannot find the drive specified` but when i add `echo` before it then it shows my code line by line. any way to fix this? I have the full code in the question.

Comment: I suggest you to: **1-** Create List.txt with _the same lines_ that the Batch file will have, that is, with no colons. **2-** When you want to create List.bat, just do a `copy /Y List.txt List.bat`. This method achieve the same intended result of your code (unless there are more requirements you have not listed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not rely on `delims` to remove leading colons, because any number of them would be stripped:

```
@echo off
>list.bat (FOR /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('""%__APPDIR__%FINDSTR.EXE" /BN ":::" "List.txt""') do (
    set "line=%%L"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!line:*::::=!
    ENDLOCAL
))
```

There are 4 colons `::::`, because I used `FINDSTR` which adds a colon in front to ensure that the line is not void.

---

## Conclusion

Don't add colons to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!
Credits go to Gerhard.
Working code is below:

```
@(for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%L in ('type list.txt ^|findstr /b ":::"') do @echo %%L)>list.cmd
```

This code extracts every line form **list.txt** removes the colons and makes **list.cmd** Worked for me. My code below:

```
@echo off
if not exist Run.bat goto start
del Run.bat
goto start
:start
if exist Output.xtf del Output.xtf
if not exist Input.xtf goto makefiles
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Loading .XTF file please wait!
echo.
echo.
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (Input.xtf) do (
set /a N+=1
echo ^:::: %%a^ >>Output.xtf
)
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Done! finalizing loading
echo.
echo.
if not exist compiler.bat goto makbatchcomplier
if not exist Output.xtf goto makefiles1
call compiler.bat
exit

:makbatchcomplier
(for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%L in ('findstr /b :::: "%~f0"') do echo %%L) >compiler.bat
:::: @(for /f "tokens=* delims=:" %%L in ('type Output.xtf ^|findstr /b "::::"') do @echo %%L)>Run.bat
:::: start Run.bat
:::: del Output.xtf
:::: del compiler.bat
:::: exit
call compiler.bat
exit
:makefiles
echo >Input.xtf
exit
:makefiles1
echo >Output.xtf
call compiler.bat
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned in the comments, all you've effectively done is create a copy of `Input.xtf` named `run.bat`, then ran that!

Here's how I've interpreted your own provided code:

- `Input.xtf` is an empty file or has unknown content.
- `Output.xtf` is each non empty line of `Input.xtf` but prepended with `::::`.
- `run.bat` is the content of `Output.xtf`, but with leading `::::` removed, which means it is the same as `Input.xtf`
- `compiler.bat` is each line of this script, (`list.cmd`), which begins with `::::`, it creates and runs `run.bat`, then deletes both `Output.xtf`, and itself.

Based upon that assessment your provided script could just as easily have looked like the following, *(and even then, you wouldn't get to read `Loading .XTF file please wait!`, because the `CLS` command would effectively clear it before you had time to read it).*

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF

IF NOT EXIST "Input.xtf" (
    CD.> "Input.xtf" 2> NUL
    EXIT /B
)

COPY /Y "Input.xtf" "Run.bat" 2> NUL || EXIT /B

CLS
ECHO=
ECHO=
ECHO=
ECHO=
ECHO Loading .XTF file please wait!
ECHO=
ECHO=

CLS
ECHO=
ECHO=
ECHO=
ECHO=
ECHO Done! finalizing loading
ECHO=
ECHO=

START "Run.bat"
EXIT /B
```

Additionally, as `Input.xtf` could contain absolutely nothing, *(because you created a 0 byte file, if it didn't exist)*, it is possible that, `CD.> "Input.xtf"` followed by `CD.> "Run.bat"` is all you've done! I would assume that isn't what you wanted to do, so it may be better to check if `Input.xtf`, exists and has content instead. Removing the unnecessary `ECHO` lines, the finished script could look like this:

```batch-file
@IF NOT EXIST "Input.xtf" CD.> "Input.xtf" 2> NUL
@"%__APPDIR__%FIND.EXE" /V "" "Input.xtf" 1> NUL || EXIT /B
@COPY /Y "Input.xtf" "Run.bat" 2> NUL || EXIT /B
@"Run.bat"
```